# Aggregating relationships via cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am fairly certain I have seen it somewhere but all keywords I have tried came up empty.

I have a graph that connects persons and companies via documents:

> (:Person/:Company)-[ ]-(:Document)-[ ]-(:Person/:Company)

What I would like to do is return a graph that shows the connection between persons and companies directly with the relationship strength based on the number of connections between them.

I get the data with

```
MATCH (p)-[]-(d:Document)-[]-(c)
WHERE p:Person or p:Company and c:Person or c:Company
WITH p,c, count(d) as rel
RETURN p,rel,c
```

However in the Neo4J-Browser, the nodes appear without any relationships. Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to create some kind of meta relationship?

Comment: Double click a node to pop open the relationships.

Comment: But then it opens alle the relationships via the documents. I would like to have the relationships displayed directly between the person/company nodes.

Comment: Match (p:Person)-[]-(d:Document)-[]-(c:Company) to select should be enough since there is no direction on the relationships.

Comment: Then you have to have an alias on the relationships and return them as well.

Comment: But I don't want to return those relationsships. I have a data model (:Person/:Company)-[ ]-(:Document)-[ ]-(:Person/:Company) and would like to visualize in the Neo4J-Browser als  (:Person/:Company)-[ number of connections]-(:Person/:Company) without actually changing the underlying data model.

Comment: Alright, yeah that probably is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install APOC Procedures, you'll be able to create [virtual relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels) which are used for visualization but aren't actually stored in the db.

```
MATCH (p)-[]-(d:Document)-[]-(c)
WHERE (p:Person or p:Company AND c:Person or c:Company)
 AND  id(p) < id(c)
WITH p,c, count(d) as relStrength
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(p,'REL',{strength:relStrength}, c) YIELD rel
RETURN p,rel,c
```

I also added a predicate on ids of p and c so you don't repeat the same two nodes with p and c switched.